# TableViewController , SearchBar and TableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar, cell-array

When I searching and after filtered select in displays row that opens only the first letter DetailView (for example A letter).Others letters don't open. NSLog and breakpoint not helping. I don't understand what is the problem.

```
     - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSString *keyTitle = cell.textLabel.text;

        NSDictionary *peopleUnderLetter = [self.propertyList objectForKey:self.letters[indexPath.section]];

        __block NSDictionary *selectedPerson = nil;

        [peopleUnderLetter enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull key, id  _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

            if ([key isEqualToString:keyTitle]) {

                selectedPerson = obj;

                *stop = YES;

            }

        }];

        if (selectedPerson) {

            DetailViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
            // Push the view controller.
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

            [vc setDictionaryGeter:selectedPerson];
        }

    }

#pragma mark Search Display Delegate Methods

-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString

{

    [filteredNames removeAllObjects];
    if (searchString.length > 0) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [search] %@", self.searchBar.text];

        for (NSString *letter in letters) {
            NSArray *matches = [[self.propertyList[letter] allKeys]filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

            [filteredNames addObjectsFromArray:matches];

        }

    }

    return YES;

}
```

after selecting every cell must open the detailviewcontroller with their data.Search bar shows every letter after filtered.But when I click cell doesn't open detail view (except first cell) .

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell without seeing the whole file but it looks like your problem may be this line. You are pulling the object out of self.propertyList using the *section* not the *row*. Which makes sense as to why it works only on the first row, which would have a row of 0 and an section of 0

```
`NSDictionary *peopleUnderLetter = [self.propertyList objectForKey:self.letters[indexPath.section]];`
```

Try changing it to :

```
`NSDictionary *peopleUnderLetter = [self.propertyList objectForKey:self.letters[indexPath.row]];`
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But nothing changed.

Comment: If you want more information just say it to me by answers and I will edit my question and then you will edit your answer

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line above  "if (selectedPerson) {" and tap on a row other than the first row is selecterPerson nil?

Comment: Yes.selectedPerson = nil

Comment: Perhaps something is wrong with your comparison here then : "key isEqualToString:keyTitle" could the keys of the peopleUnderLetter dictionary be different than the titles of your rows? Perhaps compare with both set to .lowercaseString. Also, try adding a breakpoint before your enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock and be sure that peopleUnderLetter is the correct dictionary you're looking for

Comment: I added nslog after [peopleUnderletter enumerateKey...]
Xcode shows me together 3 nslog message. 
In my first letter have 3 value